# AWS S3 PHP 2.0 - How to upload an image from computer to a bucket?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, upload, amazon-s3

I've been trying to figure out how to push an image to an S3 bucket using the new PHP 2.0 SDK. All I've found are tutorials for how to upload an image from your web server rather than from a local computer.
Here is the code that I'm using

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucketname,
    'Key'    => $filename,
    'SourceFile' => $path,
    'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg',
    'StorageClass' => 'STANDARD'
));
```

`$filename` is just the file name that I want to appear in the bucket and `$path` is the local path to the file on my computer. This puts a file onto the bucket but when I try to open the image, it just shows up as an empty screen with the no image thumb nail. I checked and it seems to only be uploading like 30 bytes. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure why there is an issue, because the code is correct (though, if `$path` contains the path to a .jpg or .jpeg, the SDK can detect the `ContentType` automatically and you don't have to provide it).

Comment: You said, "when I try to open the image, it just shows up as an empty screen with the no image thumb nail."

Where are trying to open the issue from?

Answer (score 2):

So in order to upload you need to specify the Body as well. So if you're uploading from your computer this would be the code

```
$s3 = $aws->get('s3');
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmpFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$imageType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
// Upload a publicly accessible file.
// The file size, file type, and MD5 hash are automatically calculated by the SDK
try {
    $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucketname,
        'Key' => $filename,
        'Body'   => fopen($tmpFile, 'r'),
        'ACL' => 'public-read',
        'ContentType' => $imageType,
        'StorageClass' => 'STANDARD'
    ));
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n";
}
```

where $tmpFile is the path to your file on your computer. I'm using an upload mechanism hence why i use temp. but you can just put the static path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and Shahin's answer is correct, you can set 
`'Body'   => fopen($tmpFile, 'r'),`

However when I did this on my WAMP localhost, I got the error

`Warning: fopen(C:\Windows\Temp\phpBDF3.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

This seems to be a windows permissions issue, and you can resolve it by copying the windows temp file to another temp file in a directory where there are no permissions problems (eg web root):

```
// $tmpFile was 'C:\Windows\Temp\php8A16.tmp';
// create a new temp file in webroot, and copy the windows tempfile there
$new_temp_location = tmpfile();
$new_temp_location = basename($tmpFile);
copy($tmpFile, $new_temp_location);

// now put the file in the bucket
try {
    $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucketname,
        'Key' => $filename,
        'Body'   => fopen($new_temp_location, 'r'),
        'ACL' => 'public-read',
        'ContentType' => $imageType,
        'StorageClass' => 'STANDARD'
    ));
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n";
}
```

It worked for me - hope it saves someone else some time...

**EDIT:**

Or slightly simpler, you can use

```
'SourceFile'   => $new_temp_location,
```

Instead of

```
'Body'   => fopen($new_temp_location, 'r'),
```